# Validate the calendar view of a page displays current month and date - behat test automation script

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I am new to test automation and currently we are using a combination of behat + mink + selenium to automate tests. I want to check whether the calendar view displays the correct month and date. Here is my gherkin script:

```
Feature: Users see the current date when the calendar view is clicked! 
@javascript
Scenario: As a registered user, when I click on calendar, the page should display current date (mm-dd)
    Given I go to "URL"
    When I fill in "username" with "username"
    When I fill in "password" with "password"
    Then I press "edit-submit"
    Then I follow "calendar"
    Then I should see "June 28"
```

This is what I added in the FeatureContext.php file:

```
public function getCurrentDate() {
    return $this->currentDate()->format('Y-m-d');
}

protected function currentDate() {
    return new Date();
}
```

Since it this test should be automated I would like to change the last step in my script to something like this:

```
Then I should see "current date (mm-dd)"
```

I am not sure if it is even possible but like I said earlier, I am new to behat and I'm not sure how would I implement something like this. I am using Behat with mink and selenium.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and wanted to post a solution in case someone needed it in the future:

Add this to your FeatureContext.php file.
Comments on top of each function explain what it does!

First function:

```
// call currentDate() to fetch and format the date (month year)
public function getCurrentDate() {
    return $this->currentdate = $this->currentDate()->format('F Y');
}
```

Second function:

```
// Get current date time
protected function currentDate() {
    return new DateTime();
}
```

Third function:

```
//month year date matcher does not take any arguments
/**
 * Checks, that page contains specified text.
 *
 * @Then /^match current month year with page$/
 */
public function MonthYearDateMatcher()
{
    $this->assertSession()->pageTextContains($this->fixStepArgument($this->getCurrentDate()));
}
```